# Selecting a fraction of documents by mod(ObjectId)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a large collection that I'm running an aggregation pipeline on.  I have MongoDB 2.4.  I'm hitting up against the 16 MB limit.  I know I can solve this by upgrading to 2.6, but that's not an option for me.

The other way I can get below the 16 MB limit is to break the aggregation up into a few pieces, then combine the partial results in my application code.  The field I would need to split on is an ObjectId.  Essentially, what I want is for my $match stage to use something like:

my_objid_field: {$mod: [10, n]}

and I'll run the query 10 times, for different values of n.  But, I can't figure out how to express that.

---

A typical document looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("514cf080358a7c3fd4113f84"),
    "a" : 1,
    "c" : "US",
    "d" : ISODate("2013-03-23T00:00:00Z"),
    "st" : ObjectId("4fcfa494c212e76b890004a2"),
    "si" : 0,
    "so" : ObjectId("4e9e58e62b28686b47e71cdf"),
    "t" : ISODate("2013-03-23T00:00:00.779Z"),
    "u" : ObjectId("4fe9845a8596aa3d990014cf"),
    "se" : "dYJgW8w/kcCIJK08"
}
```

and the pipeline, from db.currentOp(), is:

```
        "pipeline" : [
            {
                "$match" : {
                    "$or" : [
                        {
                            "du" : {
                                "$gt" : 25
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "du" : {
                                "$exists" : false
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "bu" : {
                        "$exists" : false
                    },
                    "t" : {
                        "$gte" : ISODate("2013-03-23T00:00:00Z"),
                        "$lt" : ISODate("2013-03-24T00:00:00Z")
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$group" : {
                    "c" : {
                        "$sum" : 1
                    },
                    "_id" : {
                        "t" : "$st",
                        "o" : "$so"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
```

The query matches about 20 million documents, and results in about 200 thousand documents.  The query runs for a few minutes, then fails with "aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)".

Comment: Where are you breaking the limit? In the pipeline or in the result? You might better express your problem by including the aggregation operation in your question, then it becomes clear what to break up.

Answer (score 1):

Your result is too large so probably the best thing to do is implement [**`$limit`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) at the end of your pipeline:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // same $match
    // same $group
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
    { "$limit": 1000 }      // or whatever you can go to without breaking
])
```

The catch there is [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) as you aggregate results are not guaranteed to be in order and are likely in the order of discovery. You need the results in order for what you do next.

On the next invocation you take the "last" `_id` value from aggregation and alter your match pipeline as follows:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match" : {
        "st": { "$gte": ObjectId("4fcfa494c212e76b890004a2") }, // part of last result
        "$or" : [
            { "du" : { "$gt" : 25 } },
            { "du" : { "$exists" : false } }
        ],
        "bu" : { "$exists" : false },
        "t" : {
            "$gte" : ISODate("2013-03-23T00:00:00Z"),
            "$lt" : ISODate("2013-03-24T00:00:00Z")
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "t" : "$st", "o" : "$so" },
        "c" : { "$sum" : 1 },
    }},
    { "$match": { 
        "_id": {              // Both elements of the last seen _id
            "$ne": {
                "t": ObjectId("4fcfa494c212e76b890004a2"),
                "o": ObjectId("4e9e58e62b28686b47e71cdf")
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
    { "$limit": 1000 }
])
```

Since you are using "st" in your aggregation results and the supplied value was the last value seen in the last set of results, then all values that are less than that value are excluded.

The final `$match` is there since while the first would have mostly excluded results the "combined key" needs to be excluded. This is essentially why you cannot just do [**`$gt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) in the first `$match` as there could still be larger values for the second element in the combination that share the first.

You still `$sort` and `$limit` on each iteration and keep going until the number of returned results is less than the limit you have set.

There is also the [**`$skip`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) operator for the aggregation pipeline, but that is not very performant as you would be increasing the "skip" per each 1000 documents right up to processing your 200,000 result. So very slow.

The best approach is to exclude the values already seen and then cut the pipeline results all the way through.

The main problem here is the _id combination that is essentially the result. It would make it very difficult to just find a "split" of the range of both in combination. So the compromise here is a query that will get faster with each iteration.

Finally, for performance reasons it now becomes important in include the "st" field in a compound index as this can be used in the `$match` as it's most efficient form.

Moving to MongoDB 2.6 should be considered though as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks.  That's an interesting approach, and sounds like it should work.  Unfortunately, moving to 2.6 just isn't an option.  We've tried 2.6; it breaks some of our existing application code (I don't recall the details right now of what broke).

Comment: @RoySmith None of the above relies on MongoDB 2.6. The recommendation is made at the end because you really should do so. I am not personally aware of anything that "breaks code" other than some possible issues with geoSpatial queries that has generally been resolved since 2.6.3. And 2.6.4 is about to be released. There are some minor things that were actually "bugs" in prior releases where some query forms that should not work but did. But there is nothing version specific below 2.2 here that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a good idea to perform database fraction, using modulo on _id, since they may not be equally spread along time.

However here is a way to do it.

First you need to convert id to timestamp:

```
{
  $divide: [
   { $toLong: { $toDate: "$_id" } },
   1000,
  ],
}
```

Then you can evaluate and compare its modulo:

```
{
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      4,
      { $mod: [
        { $divide: [{ $toLong: { $toDate: "$_id" } }, 1000] },
        5,
      ] }
    ],
  },
}
```

In this exemple i'm performing `_id mod 5 === 4`